# Use IServiceProvider in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AddLogging extension method

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, nlog

i have an app in which i would like to configure NLog with a configuration file like this

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder
                    .ClearProviders()
                    .AddNLog(projectInfo.GetNLogConfigPath())
                    .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
            })
```

However i would like to get this file location from a singleton service from DI. I searched for a service provider but all i found is the loggingBuilder service collection (for now `projectInfo` is a local variable).

Is there a way to get service provider in the AddLogging extension method action ?

Comment: At this point in time, there exists no `IServiceProvider`. The `IServiceProvider` gets created only later on, when the container gets created. This likely means you will have to compose the singleton service (with its possible dependencies) by hand and register that instance in the DI system. This allows you to also use the service inside your configure lambda.

Comment: @Steven ok, i thought the action was executed later like lambda when registering singleton.

Comment: See: https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `AddNLog()` extension method from [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/)

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
   {
      loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
      loggingBuilder.AddNLog(serviceProvider => {
         var config = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration)) as IConfiguration;
         var filename = config["MyValues:Value1"].ToString();
         return NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromFile(filename).LogFactory;
      });
   })
```

Then you have this appsettings.json:

```
{ 
   "MyValues": {
      "Value1": "NLog.config"
   }
}
```

Notice you could also just have the [NLog-configuration in the appsettings.json](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json).